# Why does Visual Studio build for Any CPU gives different floating point results on 32bit and 64bit OS?

Tags: c#, build, precision, floating-accuracy

I wrote a C# application that performs complex calculations (least square adjustments of measurements). I built this app using Any CPU configuration in Visual Studio. All worked well until I got an email stating that in one specific case there was a different result on 2 different PCs. After some debugging I discovered that app that was on 32bit OS had slightly wrong results (12th decimal place) in comparison with 64bit OS. In that specific case final result was way off, because it showed that wrong measurement didn't pass the tests.

I then built 2 versions of the app, 32bit and 64bit and both versions worked as expected and gavee the same results.

So now I would like to understand what is going on under the "hood", how is it possible that Any CPU version performs floating point calculations differently than 32bit and 64bit builds? Optimize code option was off all the time.

Comment: What CPU? I remember there were specific CPU with issues in floating points, somehow, vague, long time ago.

Comment: If you are talking about `float` and `double` then you need to be prepared that the same operation can produce slightly different results.

Comment: I think that in this specific case it doesn't matter. I installed 32bit and 64bit Windows 7 on my i7-4770 and error was still present.

Comment: Please see http://floating-point-gui.de/ "What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic".

Comment: It should not matter  - a float, in C#, is a float. Same size, same IEEE standard. The difference may be some implementation detail in the CPU - either bug level, or crappy tests on your side (resutls are NOT something that may be identical, so your test may test for equality instead of difference smaller epsilon)

Comment: @ Polyfun I know that, it's not the topic right now.

Comment: @TomTom  I always compare with epsilon. Same input, same application, same CPU, different build settings and different results

Comment: dotnet versdion? You are aware they now have a github website? I suggest taking the issue there (becasue the developers acutally DO care about that stuff, a lot, and they may answer. That said, better test with current version, not something old.

Comment: @TomTom .NET 4.5. I will check on GitHub. i don't know why, but I always ask questions first on StackOverflow

Comment: I know, but this is VERY specific and it LOOKS like a bug, so the core developers are really where this should go. THis is not so much a "I have a programming" more a "I think i have a bug" sitaution.

Comment: @TomTom: C# does not conform to the IEEE 754 floating-point standard. It may be holding values with exrended precision in registers and only reducing them to nominal precision when spilling them to memory, and the register use pattern may be different in 32-bit and 64-bit. And there are other reasons floating-point operations can differ.

Answer (score 0):

my first ever post here.
I think i must show something up to all interested in that matter, related exactly to what zoran have had posted.

Simply, write down this code:

```
float a = -0.003124237f;
float b =  0.009375687f;
float c = 88.4625f;
float abc = a + b + c;
float cab = c + a + b;
```

Make then 2 tests, use x86 ,and x64 builds
In both tests watch out the "abc" and the "cab"
Have seen something?
Well i do. This must be named "bug". Not a programe bug, its a bug of something deep into the CPU I guess.
Someone with real good understanding may help us know more about this issue.
Thanks in advance, and thanks zoran who opened such similar issue posting here.

( for those who are too busy to test my "code", here my results:

x86 :
abc = cab = 88.46875

x64 :
abc = 88.46875, but.....
cab = 88.46876

Other words, x64 can not calculate as precise as x86 builder.
The word "precise" is very "soft" and "gentle".
I honesly name this "real bug", its just pretty inacceptable issue.
Indeed.)

Comment: here no answer at all. See my point please, why build x64 gives incorrect calculation, so can you answer this?